# Kubernetes : Deploy only in one node-pool

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm currently creating a Kubernetes cluster for a production environment.
In my cluster, I have 2 node-pool, let's call them `api-pool` and `web-pool`

In my `api-pool`, I have 2 nodes with 4CPU and 15Gb of RAM each.

I'm trying to deploy 8 replicas of my api in my `api-pool`, each replicas should have 1CPU and 3.5Gi of RAM.

My api.deployment.yaml looks something like this :

```yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-dev
spec:
  replicas: 8
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api-docker
        image: //MY_IMAGE
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: api-dev-env
          - secretRef:
              name: api-dev-secret
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: "3.5Gi"
```

But my problem is that **Kubernetes is deploying the pods on nodes on my `web-pool` as well as in my `api-pool`** but I want those pods to be deployed only in my `api-pool`.

I tried to label my nodes of the `api-pool` to use a selector that matches labels but it doesn't work and I'm not sure it's supposed to work that way.

**How can I precise to K8s to deploy those 8 replicas only in my `api-pool` ?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [nodeselector](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#nodeselector) which is the simplest recommended form of node selection constraint.

label the nodes of api-pool with pool=api

```
kubectl label nodes nodename pool=api
```

Add `nodeSelector` in pod spec.

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api-dev
spec:
  replicas: 8
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-api
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-api
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: api-docker
        image: //MY_IMAGE
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: api-dev-env
          - secretRef:
              name: api-dev-secret
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: "1"
            memory: "3.5Gi"
      nodeSelector:
        pool: api
```

For mode advanced use cases you can use [node affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity).